# how to disable grid view onclick highlight the grid item. XAML UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

[image: Gridview of clickable Buttons]

In the image below I have a grid view of round Buttons & for some reason the grid view is also clickable and stays highlighted after you click the grid view box

```xml
 <GridView x:Name="ShowmanshipGridview" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Height="274" Canvas.Top="107" Width="374" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Canvas.Left="12">
                    <Button
                    Content="4.0"
                    CornerRadius="90,90,90,90"
                    Height="88" Width="88" FontSize="48" Foreground="White" Click="Showmanship_Button_Click" >
                        <Button.FocusVisualSecondaryBrush>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{ThemeResource SystemChromeGrayColor}"/>
                        </Button.FocusVisualSecondaryBrush>
                        <Button.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource ButtonBlue}"/>
                        </Button.Background>
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                    Content="4.1"
                    CornerRadius="90,90,90,90"
                    Height="88" Width="88" FontSize="48" Foreground="White" Click="Showmanship_Button_Click">
                        <Button.FocusVisualSecondaryBrush>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{ThemeResource SystemChromeGrayColor}"/>
                        </Button.FocusVisualSecondaryBrush>
                        <Button.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource ButtonBlue}"/>
                        </Button.Background>
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                    Content="4.2"
                    CornerRadius="90,90,90,90"
                    Height="88" Width="88" FontSize="48" Foreground="White" Click="Showmanship_Button_Click">
                        <Button.FocusVisualSecondaryBrush>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{ThemeResource SystemChromeGrayColor}"/>
                        </Button.FocusVisualSecondaryBrush>
                        <Button.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource ButtonBlue}"/>
                        </Button.Background>
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                    Content="4.3"
                    CornerRadius="90,90,90,90"
                    Height="88" Width="88" FontSize="48" Foreground="White" Click="Showmanship_Button_Click">
                        <Button.FocusVisualSecondaryBrush>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{ThemeResource SystemChromeGrayColor}"/>
                        </Button.FocusVisualSecondaryBrush>
                        <Button.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource ButtonBlue}"/>
                        </Button.Background>
                    </Button>
                  
                    
  </GridView>
```

Comment: Does the following answer work， Any updates for this thread?

Answer (score 0):

The pointer hove rectangle like the above screenshot is `ListViewItemPresenter` style where in GridViewItem. if you want to remove them, you could edit the default  `GridViewItemBackgroundPointerOver` value as `Transparent`  and set `GridViewItemRevealBorderThemeThickness` as zero at same time. You could copy the following and into `Application.Resources` directly.

```
<Thickness x:Key="GridViewItemRevealBorderThemeThickness">0</Thickness>
<SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent" x:Key="GridViewItemBackgroundPointerOver" />
```